# PDFView on landscape on android studio

Tags: java, android

I have created a PDF reader on the Android Studio platform using [barteksc URL = https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer] library. I downloaded the library and managed to open the pdf file.. whenever I tried to landscape a page of that pdf its goes to the 1st page of that pdf. Like I am on page number 10, when I turn on the landscape mode its goes to page number 1.how can I solve this problem?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity2">

  <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
      android:id="@+id/pdfView"
      android:background="@color/black"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
PDFView book1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    book1=(PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

    book1.fromAsset("Problems-of-Life-and-Mind.-Second-series.pdf")
            .spacing(10)
            .load();

}
```

}

Comment: Could you please add some code showing what you have tried until now ?

Comment: Have a look now

Answer (score 0):

Just add a particular layout to **Landscape Mode**

```
<activity android:name=".<YourActivity>"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```